# Cannot compile unordered_set contains function from cppreference.com

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I feel like this would only happen to me but here is an oddity I found when I was looking up the contains function for unordered_set. Here is the link where I tried to run the example below [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains)

[image]

This seems quite odd to me that contains() does not exist yet it does? I get the same error on my compiler as well. Did the std library lose a neuron?

Comment: `contains(x)` is only available in C++20. The traditional alternative is `count(x) > 0`.

Comment: @john: well, would you mind defining traditional? Because I've always used `set.find(x) != set.end()`

Comment: @Jack `find` seems superfluous to me when all you need is membership. But OK, 'a traditional alternative' would be better.

Comment: Also asking for count is superfluous when all you need is membership. That's why they actually added `contains(x)` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library that ships with your compiler most likely just doesn't support this function yet. `contains()` was added in C++20. And C++20 is not even out yet…

As far as I can tell, the latest version of the propsal containing the `contains()` member function is [P0919r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r3.html). You can check the C++20 implementation status for GCC [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020). If you do, you will see that, at the time of writing, it's not implemented yet…

Comment: I see then why is it on the cppreference website? Seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying, but the API is decided by committee and comes out months or even years before all the various compilers start supporting it

Comment: @Wolfy if you look closely, you will see that the [cppreference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) has a little green tag next to basically every entity that says when the respective entity was introduced/removed

Comment: cppreference does add things from C++20 drafts, which are based on committee votes though not yet finalized. But right now you can't really expect compilers and standard libraries to have implemented everything marked "(C++20)".  Some of it is experimentally available with the g++ "-std=c++2a" switch, but it's still a moving target.

Comment: I just noticed that, sorry should of seen that.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on cppreference, this member function is only supported as from C++20.

Fortunately, there's an easy workaround:

```
if(example.find(2)!=example.end()) {...}
```

If this is too uggly,  you can define:

```
template <class C, class T>
bool contains (C &c, T t) {
    return c.find(t)!=c.end(); 
}
```

and write

```
if(contains(example,2)) { ... }
```